# Installing ROS on Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric Ocelot

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is actually possible to install ROS on the upcoming Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric Ocelot through the ros repository?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11426/installing-ros-on-ubuntu-11.10-oneric-ocelot/) by [thek3nger](https://answers.ros.org/users/1169/thek3nger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No Ubuntu Oneric packages are currently in the repository.

I would not expect to see them there until after Oneric is officially released by Ubuntu.

The answer above refers to the Ubuntu binaries. You can probably check out ROS sources and compile them on Oneric. There may be some problems with system dependencies or perhaps a new compiler version. If so, please report them. The ROS package maintainers will want to fix them.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-09**:
Oneiric debs have been built and are now available.

**Comment by [thek3nger](https://answers.ros.org/users/1169/thek3nger/) on 2011-10-05**:
Ok. I think that I can wait for a week. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried to follow the ROS installation instructions for Ubuntu 11.04 on my machine that is running Ubuntu 11.10. I can install the "bare bones" version ok but none of the higher functionality. I think the problem is the dependency on something called *libglut3-dev*. I tried installing each section of ROS individually and tracked the problem to this library. Can the ROS package maintainers help me get the full version installed on Ubuntu 11.10?

---

Originally posted by [Steven](https://answers.ros.org/users/1273/steven/) with karma: 11 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-31**:
Using the natty 11.04 binaries might get you somewhere, but the oneiric 11.10 binaries are now mostly there.  We are working on bringing them all up to date, but each package must be checked and if a change is required rereleased.  Current status is at http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html